# Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'backgroundColor') from chartjs-plugin-annotation

Tags: chartjs-plugin-annotation

Seeing a console error intermittently while navigating form some different application, the chart js plugin annotation gives me error saying

```
instrument.js:122 TypeError: Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'backgroundColor') at qe (chartjs-plugin-annotation.esm.js:778:9) at ge (chartjs-plugin-annotation.esm.js:720:17) at O.resolveElementProperties (chartjs-plugin-annotation.esm.js:939:12) at vt (chartjs-plugin-annotation.esm.js:2065:32) at Object.afterUpdate (chartjs-plugin-annotation.esm.js:2232:5) at zt (helpers.segment.js:79:19) at dn._notify (chart.js:5073:17) at dn.notify (chart.js:5056:29) at n.notifyPlugins (chart.js:6338:30) at n.update (chart.js:5899:14) at new n (chart.js:5652:18)
```

I am using box annotation, This works on manual reloading the page.